# OpenCV Active Contour doesn't work well for Biomed data compared it's Matlab version

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on translating Matlab version active contour to OpenCV. It seems that OpenCV has its own version of active contour but deprecated then. I am curious about how different between this version with Matlab version. So I did a comparison experiment. Given a MRI brain image and an initial boundary , I applied both Matlab and OpenCV version active contour to segment the white matter in brain.

For both Matlab and OpenCV, I choose gradient(edge) method of active contour. I then labeled the results on the image. The red curve is initial boundary while the green curve is final boundary.

The Matlab code is:

```
clear
clc
I = imread('brain.png');
IMaskS = imread('shrinkMask.png');

figure(1)
imshow(I)
hold on
visboundaries( IMaskS, 'color', 'r'); 
bwSnake = activecontour(I,  IMaskS, 250, 'edge','ContractionBias',-0.45,'SmoothFactor',0.7);
finalBoundary = bwboundaries(bwSnake);
visboundaries(finalBoundary, 'color', 'g');
```

[image]

It seems that Matlab does a really good job when choosing the appropriate parameters. The "ContractionBias" parameter (refer it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/activecontour.html)) is really useful for controlling the curve to shrink or expand.

However, the OpenCV version active contour seems doesn't work at all. I use slider bar to change the parameters alpha, beta and gamma but cannot get a descend result. It seems that the curve doesn't expand no matter how I set the parameters. I use OpenCV 2.4.13.3 and active contour can be found in legacy folder as snakes.cpp. Chek [OpenCV github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4.13.3/modules/legacy) or more specifically [snakes.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.13.3/modules/legacy/src/snakes.cpp). The OpenCV test code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

IplImage *image = 0; 
IplImage *image2 = 0; 
IplImage *imageMask = 0;
using namespace std;

int ialpha = 10;
int ibeta = 40;
int igamma = 50;


void onChange(int pos)
{

    if (image2) cvReleaseImage(&image2);
    if (image) cvReleaseImage(&image);
    if (imageMask) cvReleaseImage(&imageMask);

    image2 = cvLoadImage("brain.png", 1); 
    image = cvLoadImage("brain.png", 0);
    imageMask = cvLoadImage("shrinkMask.png", 0);



    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* contours = 0;

    cvFindContours(imageMask, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
        CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


    if (!contours) return;
    int length = contours->total;
    if (length<10) return;
    CvPoint* point = new CvPoint[length]; 

    CvSeqReader reader;
    CvPoint pt = cvPoint(0, 0);;
    CvSeq *contour2 = contours;

    cvStartReadSeq(contour2, &reader);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM(pt, reader);
        point[i] = pt;
    }
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);


    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        int j = (i + 1) % length;
        cvLine(image2, point[i], point[j], CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }

    float alpha = ialpha / 100.0f;
    float beta = ibeta / 100.0f;
    float gamma = igamma / 100.0f;

    CvSize size;
    size.width = 3;
    size.height = 3;
    CvTermCriteria criteria;
    criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER;
    criteria.max_iter = 500;
    criteria.epsilon = 0.1;
    cvSnakeImage(image, point, length, &alpha, &beta, &gamma, CV_VALUE, size, criteria, 1);


    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        int j = (i + 1) % length;
        cvLine(image2, point[i], point[j], CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
    delete[]point;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    cvNamedWindow("win1", 0);
    cvCreateTrackbar("alpha", "win1", &ialpha, 100, onChange);
    cvCreateTrackbar("beta", "win1", &ibeta, 100, onChange);
    cvCreateTrackbar("gamma", "win1", &igamma, 100, onChange);
    //cvResizeWindow("win1", 696, 520);
    cvResizeWindow("win1", 256, 256);
    onChange(0);

    for (;;)
    {
        if (cvWaitKey(40) == 27) break;
        cvShowImage("win1", image2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Is there anything I did wrong or this version of active contour in OpenCV is completely useless? I checked the [snake.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.13.3/modules/legacy/src/snakes.cpp), the source code for OpenCV version active contour, it seems that it is implemented based on the theory in paper. Because of file protection, I cannot access the Matlab version active contour. Therefore, I cannot compare them directly. Since eventually, I will use OpenCV to implement stuffs, any suggestion for improving or changing  my OpenCV code will be appreciated.

I attached the original image and mask in case someone wants to repeat the test.

Thanks!

[image: Brain Image]
[image: Mask]

Comment: Maybe this can help? From the images looks like you have a similar problem of this post: [Active Contour Models in OpenCV 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894542/active-contour-models-in-opencv-3-0). It's C++, but you could still take some hints from the comment section.

Comment: @Bit Thank you! It seems that OpenCV version snake only works for binary image, which I think is very weird.